# Pyrocache vs Memcached

Tags: memcached, pyrocms, bigdata

I have used PyroCMS for some projects, I love it so much. I am current developing another website based on it. In my website, I need to work on a big database, it is not really big but big enough to require the cache module.
I am hesitating to use either built-in Pyrocache library or third-party cache, memcached. So why should I use memcached? Can the Pyrocache manage large data as well? What are the advantages of Pyrocache in comparison with memcached?

In my website, it will display information on over 200.000 locations, data are static for a long time. I want to use the cache to cache all location datas, so when user request, it directly returns the result without query the database. Can Pyrocache suite for my scenario?

Thanks in advanced,
Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyrocache stores data locally (cannot be shared between multiple web servers) on disk (not terribly fast).  Memcache stores data in memory (fast), and a memcache server/pool can be shared between multiple web servers.

The main advantages of pyrocache would be simplicity both in invocation and installation -- you don't have to install and configure memcached.

http://pyrocms.com/docs/manuals/developers/caching-data-with-pyrocache